# jitpack build failed with info: No build artifacts found

Tags: android, jitpack

I have a problem with publishing library to jitpack:
Here is the [JitPack's build log](https://www.jitpack.io/com/github/archerLj/AndroidGraphicsUtils/1.0/build.log)

I was following the step of [Publish an Android library](https://jitpack.io/docs/ANDROID/).

this is my project [build.gradle](https://github.com/archerLj/AndroidGraphicsUtils/blob/master/build.gradle)

and library [build.gradle here](https://github.com/archerLj/AndroidGraphicsUtils/blob/master/utils/build.gradle)

Comment: Your JitPack's build log is only access-able with user and password. So, I can't help